# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework. How to write async query with subquery?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

This is code which I try to async.

```cs
public void MarkAsRead(Guid id)
{
   var notificationMessages = DbContext.NotificationMessages
        .Where(nm => !nm.IsRead && nm.CreatedDate <  DbContext.NotificationMessages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).CreatedDate)
        .ToList();

        notificationMessages.ForEach(nm => nm.IsRead = true);
        DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have alrady tried this, but it didn't work

```cs
public async Task MarkAsRead(Guid id)
{
   var notificationMessages = await DbContext.NotificationMessages
        .Where( async nm => !nm.IsRead && nm.CreatedDate < await DbContext.NotificationMessages.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id).Result.CreatedDate)
        .ToListAsync();

        notificationMessages.ForEach(nm => nm.IsRead = true);
        await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The main problem that I can't get subquery field `CreatedDate`.

The error message says:

> 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no
>   accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression that is passed to `Where` is simply converted to SQL by EF, so there is no need to try and make it async.

The `ToListAsync` method executes the query on the database asynchronously, so should be awaited:

```
public async Task MaskAsRead(Guid id)
{
   var notificationMessages = await DbContext.NotificationMessages
        .Where(nm => !nm.IsRead && nm.CreatedDate < DbContext.NotificationMessages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id).Result.CreatedDate)
        .ToListAsync();

    notificationMessages.ForEach(nm => nm.IsRead = true);
    await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```